# Need to search (and navigate to the searched word) within in an ASPX page

Tags: asp.net, full-text-search, anchor, htmlgenericcontrol

Scenario: ASP.NET site. 
In Instruct.ASPX code-behind, I generate the contents of the page and they are well formatted using TABLE, TR, TD, Hyperlink, Anchor tags etc. The entire content is assigned to InstructionsDiv as shown below.

```
HtmlGenericControl InstructionsDiv = new HtmlGenericControl("Div");
```

Since the contents of the page is growing, USERS want to be able to search within the page.
I would like to provide a text button and when they click on SEARCH button, I would like to wrap the word they are looking for within an anchor tag and start search.

Is this the correct way? If so, what do I need to take care of when they click on SEARCH button? If the search has many results, I want them to continue. Pretty much I am looking for a browser Ctrl+F functionality.

Any other better thoughts or suggestions, please share.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not look at using something like a jquery plugin to search via javascript.  Here is one I found after a quick search:

[jQuery Quicksearch](https://github.com/riklomas/quicksearch#readme)